# Error When Trying To Save PHP File In TextWrangler (or attempting to Enable PHP)

Tags: php, text-editor, textwrangler

I am trying to save a PHP file in TextWrangler and it keeps giving me the error:

```
You do not have sufficient privileges to perform this operation (MacOS Error code: -5000)
```

I've also tried to enable PHP by opening the file:

```
Macintosh HD:private:etc:apache2:httpd.conf
```

and editing the appropriate file but I get the same error message. Why would I be prevented from making these changes on my computer? I was assuming it would prompt me for a password but it just gave me the error. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how TextWrangler and iOS relate. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, yeah, I've been so busy with XCode it was a habit. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the answer is.

I purchased TextWrangler from the Mac App Store and the version from the App Store does not allow authenticated saves in order to meet the App Store submission guidelines (I don't know the specifics exactly).

The one that should be download is:

http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [unix file permissions](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html) if you really want to understand this, and do an `ls -al` from terminal in the directory you're editing.

Essentially, your user just doesn't have privileges, either because it isn't the owner or because writing is disabled.  Try using 'sudo' before your commands. Your password should be your user password.

You can change permissions like this:

`sudo chmod 777 filename` (makes globally writable)

`sudo chown myuser filename` (makes a new owner for file)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I started looking at that and then stumbled upon the simple answer (at least in my case). I left an answer above.